# Kotlin in VS Code - Unresolved reference for user defined class in another file

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, jvm

I'm trying to set up Kotlin for VS Code following the instructions in [this article](https://kotlin-code.com/ide/visual-studio-code/setup/), which basically says to install the Kotlin and Code Runner extensions.

So far, so good, I am able to run the following code:

App.kt:

```
fun main() {
    MyApp().printTest()
}

class MyApp {
    fun printTest() {
        println("Hello test")
    }
}
```

However, when I try to extract the *MyApp* class to another file in the same folder, I can't import it:

App.kt:

```
import MyApp.MyApp // import MyApp doesn't work also

fun main() {
    MyApp().printTest()
}
```

MyApp.kt:

```
class MyApp {
    fun printTest() {
        println("Hello test")
    }
}
```

I've tried to import the [Java Import Snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tushortz.java-imports-snippets), but it doesn't work, showing a *unresolved reference* for *MyApp*.

Am I missing some extension or VS Code configuration?

That's the command VS Code is running:

```
cd ".../testapp/src/" && kotlinc App.kt -include-runtime -d App.jar && java -jar App.jar
```

Should it reference *MyApp.kt* somehow?

Note: I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You have no project's package name defined.

Put the files `App.kt` and `MyApp.kt` in the same folder level.

In App.kt, only use

```
import MyApp // or no import at all,

fun main() {
    MyApp().printTest()
}
```

Read more about [Java/Kotlin package](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/packages.html)

Comment: I still get the unresolved reference error, either by importing or not, putting explicitly the same package name or not. I've added the command VS Code is running if that can clarify any problem.

Comment: Yeah this answer is absolutely not correct!

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code terminal simply do the following:

```
clear && printf '\e[3J' && kotlinc **/*.kt -include-runtime -d YOUR_JAR.jar && java -jar YOUR_JAR.jar
```

the "kotlinc **/*.kt will compile all Kotlin files that you need and this error should go away!

:)